# checkbox input always return null in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I recently using Laravel version 5.8, now I am little confused about how to input checkbox value to the table in the database, the checkbox value always return null, even the checkbox is selected, can anyone help me with this 
by the way, this is my form checkbox

```
    <form action="{{ $siswa->id_siswa}}/verifikasi">
    @csrf
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" name="ijazah" id="" value="true">ijazah</label>
   </form>
```

and this is my function in the controller

```
    public function approve(Request $request,$id_siswa){
    $ijazah = $request->ijazah;
    dd($ijazah);
    }
```

Comment: You need to get the data of the input like this: ```$request->input('ijazah');```

Comment: @ettdro, yeah thanks my friend, it's like your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how to get input from request.
For getting the input you should use

```
$data = $request->all();
```

That code will get all input request and store it to the array, after that you can get the ijazah input with:

```
$data['ijazah'];
```

Or if you only want to get 'ijazah' you can try this

```
$request->input('ijazah');
```

Comment: @Affandi Yusuf, yeah its work, thanks for your advice my friend